# how to organize a database to store parent/child relation

Tags: mysql, database-design

I develop a website where there is a notion of city group. Where a group is defined by a city parent and cities as childs. 
So I need to store a relation between a parent city and child cities (1:n relation).

I was wondering was is the best schema to define for that. 
For instance we would have : Paris (parent) --> Neuilly (child), Vincennes (child), St Mandé (child), etc...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4048151/330315

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
--> cities
- id (int PK)
- name (varchar)
- parent_id (int default 0 )
```

Then values like:

```
- 1,Paris, 0
- 2, Neuilly, 1
- 3, Vincennes, 1
- 4, St Mandé, 1
```

To build your list:

```
select * from cities as c0 join cities as c1 on c1.parent_id = c0.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will use self join for this

```
table :=> cities
fields :=>
- id (int PK)
- name (varchar)
- parent_city_id (int default 0 )
```

And therefore self join will be used where Join will be based on id of c1(cities Alias table1) joining  c2(cities Alias table2,treating as Second table).